# Many to Many relationship with 2 keys in one table

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am building an ASP.net application and I am using the Entity framework DBFirst. I have 2 tables. One table has 2 keys. The other table has 1 key. So the table structure;

```
Topic Table
   > Id
   > ArticleId
   > ...

Branch Table
   > Id
   > ...
```

I have a problem creating a many to many relationship since there are 2 keys in the topic table. My many to many relation table looks like this;

```
BranchTopic
   > TopicId
   > BranchId
```

How do I solve this? I want a many to many relationship between the Topic and Branch. I don't want any relationship in between the ArticleId in this relationship. When I leave out the ArticleId visual Studio shows the following error;

Error   15  Error 3024: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 503:Must specify mapping for all key properties (Id, ArticleId) of End Topic in Relationship MathematicsBranchTopic.
    C:\Users\Username\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Mathematics\Mathematics\Model.edmx  504 11  Mathematics

Comment: Actually I can't immagine an entity model that meets your requirements. I think you need an entity with Table.Id as primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify column order to specify multiple keys

[From the documentation:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx)

```
public class Passport 
{ 
    [Key] 
    [Column(Order=1)] 
    public int PassportNumber { get; set; } 
    [Key] 
    [Column(Order = 2)] 
    public string IssuingCountry { get; set; } 
    public DateTime Issued { get; set; } 
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; } 
}
```